# Zooming in google map api 3 [ios]

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

According to [Google Map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?hl=fr#DefaultControls). In IPhone

> Zooming is accomplished by a two finger pinch.

So when i tap my fingers on screen and move then map getting zoomed but after that when i release fingers from screen then zoom that i see before the map reloads is a lot more than the actual zoom that renders.

Currently, I am testing that on **IPhone 5** with **ios 7.1.2** and **IPhone 4S** with **ios 8**

I am using JQuery Mobile Framework in my app and the map is generated dynamically.
(when i create map with fixed values then it works fine)

I created fiddle in which you can see same problem.
[`Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/4wc6cjqk/1/)

Some picture of my issue
First picture map opens

[image: first]

Second picture when i try to zoom my map with finger pinch.

[image: second picture]

Third picture when i released my finger from screen.

[image: third picture]

So it cannot maintain its zoom level that show in second picture. How to solve this problem

Comment: pinch zooming doesn't return actual zoom level, because tiles aren't loaded during the zooming action. If you `console.log(mapClass.map.getZoom());` you'll get zoom level after pinch zooming is over.

Comment: in case of `webapp` only?  Because in maps app that already installed in `IPhone` it works in that way.

Comment: Your example is zooming correctly per Google's documentation. It appears that you want to simply make the map image bigger, rather than load new tiles at the final zoom level. Maybe some sort of viewport zooming would work?

Comment: Maybe. Can you please be more specific about viewport zooming. ? As i am using jquery mobile and am not want to zoom full viewport. Just the map object is my concern.

Comment: maybe native apps use iOS built-in maps. Google loads tiles while zooming.

Comment: Oww. So i think no solution of this problem for now?

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapClass.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    mapClass.map.panTo(myLatlng);
});
```

with :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapClass.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    mapClass.map.panTo(mapClass.map.center);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue (or possibly a very similar one) buy throttling the work I did in the `zoom_changed` listener. I used [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle).

Replace this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapClass.map, 'zoom_changed', myFunction);
```

With this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapClass.map, 'zoom_changed', _.throttle(myFunction,100));
```